# Truffle Compile on Windows "Could not find a suitable configuration file"

Tags: truffle, windows, compiler, truffle-compile

I am trying to do a simple Truffle Compile on window 10 using git bash but i keep getting

"Could not find a suitable configuration file"

I have tried "Truffle Compile" after running truffle init.

I am just trying to compile the sample files that came with Truffle like Metacoin

Answer (score 2):

Even, I had the same error.

> From the Doc

When using the Command Prompt on Windows, the default configuration file name can cause a conflict with the truffle executable.If this is the case, we recommend using Windows PowerShell or Git BASH as these shells do not have this conflict. Alternatively, you can rename the configuration file to ***truffle-config.js*** to avoid this conflict.

> NOTE

I tried changing the config file first i.e. **truffle.js** to **trufle-config.js**, but then I got the same error of config file missing. But when I use it **Windows PowerShell**, it works like a charm.

Hope this helps